# IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, indexoutofboundsexception

```
List<WebElement> filter_icons = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath(PropertyFile.read_obj("CONFIGURATION_MAJORMGMT_FILTER_LIST")));
filter_icons.size();
log.info("Data passed in Name Filter");

// filter EmailID
filter_icons.get(0).click();
Common.filter_textbox(driver, Name,By.xpath("//input[@id='filterText']"));
Common.click_filterbutton(driver,By.xpath("//button[text()='Apply Filter']"));

// filter Title
filter_icons.get(1).click();
Common.filter_textbox(driver, Value,By.xpath("//input[@id='filterText']"));
Common.click_filterbutton(driver,By.xpath("//button[text()='Apply Filter']"));
```

The issue with second filter click, it giving error,

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

The same code is working for other methods perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 1):

The error {{IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
}} clearly says the size of the list is 1 (means you have item only at index 0) and you are trying to *get* an item at index 1, which does not exist.

You could do

```
for (WebElement ele : filter_icons) {
    ele.click();
    Common.filter_textbox(driver, Name,By.xpath("//input[@id='filterText']"));
    Common.click_filterbutton(driver,By.xpath("//button[text()='Apply Filter']"));
}
```